# how to take javascript input and call it in html?

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to writing javascript code and calling it into html.  I'm writing code for my personal website that I'm going to create.  When a visitor enters my site, I'm prompting them for 3 pieces of information: name, company, and title.  The Javascript looks like:

```
<script>
var name =.prompt("please enter your name") 
var company =.prompt("please enter your company")
var title =.prompt("please enter your title")
</script>
```

What I'm looking to do is call these variables in the html so it creates a personalized home page for the user.  How would I be able to pull this information into the html?  I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of using the input tag and calling the variables but not quite sure how to do that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a "form" with, yes, "inputs".  Forms have "actions", which submits the form data to, say, php code on your server.  Is this what you're working toward?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this, you need to create HTML and after prompting values from user, assign these values in the HTML tags via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<html>
  <body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
       function myFunction() {
       var name =prompt("please enter your name") 
       var company =prompt("please enter your company")
       var title=prompt("please enter your title")


    if (name != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        name + company + title;
        }
      }
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```